# Actionscript 3/Flash - Air/.exe not being "selected" after button click, not registering keyboard

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have weird problem where I click (for example) start button, then when there later comes something interactive that requires keyboard press, it wont register untill I click on the stage (without pressing button). So, my .exe needs it to be "reselected" or something after using button(s). How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try set focus on for stage after stage load completely. so that you need not click on stage.

```
 stage.focus = interactiveObject; //Like button or TextField
```

More details:

[keyboardevent-stage-focus-problem-solution](http://www.mindscriptact.com/2011/08/03/as3-keyboardevent-stage-focus-problem-solution/)

[Using stage.focus](http://www.remitoffoli.com/blog/2009/05/03/as3-using-stagefocus/)

[set-focus-flash-actionscript-3](http://www.williammalone.com/briefs/how-to-set-focus-flash-actionscript-3-as3/)